# Obtendo application id e client key do parse server

Tags: android, login, parse

Estou tentando usar o parse server para realizar cadastro e login de usuário para uma aplicação Android, porém não sei onde conseguir os application e client key necessários para o código abaixo:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "application id", "client key");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

Procurei no site Back4App dentro do parse Dashboard, mas não encontrei de jeito algum, alguém poderia explicar exatamente onde estão essas informações?

Comment: Acredito que você receba sua 'key' e 'application id' depois do cadastro no site.

Comment: @icaro me cadastrei no site e criei um parse app, mas ainda não encontrei nenhuma aba que tenha essas informações

Comment: será que não precisa pagar primeiro?

Comment: @Icaro achei que era free

Comment: Tem uma area la que diz que é free - https://www.back4app.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

voce tem que criar um projeto depois va em featuring[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois core setinfgs e server

aqui esta o app id e client key
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]